# Eigenvalue problem of The Dirichlet problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis

Consider the nonlocal problem
\begin{aligned}
&u_t(x,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}J(x-y)u(y,t)dy - u(x,t),&x\in\Omega,t>0,\\
&u(x,t)=0&x\notin\Omega,t>0,\\
&u(x,0)=u_0(x).&x\in\Omega.
\end{aligned}
I try to find the first eigenvalue of an associated problem is given by
\begin{equation}
\lambda_1 = \dfrac{1}{2}\inf\limits_{u\in L^2(\Omega)}\dfrac{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}J(x-y)(u(x)-u(y))^2dxdy}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(u(x))^2dx}
\end{equation}
Where $J\in C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ is a nonnegative, radial function with $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}J(x)dx=1$.
How can i prove why $\lambda_1$ has the form above and why the infimum is attained.
I have tried multiply both side by test function $u$.

Comment: I do not understand the locution "Dirichlet problem" as applied to your problem. Considering the data specified, it seems to me this is more like a Cauchy or mixed problem with "perfectly insulating boundary" (I am using this loose physical description to say that the exterior of the of the region $\Omega$ is *unaffected* by what is happening in its interior): what is the reason beyond the choice of this specific name for the problem at hand?

Comment: this is the linear nonlocal diffusion problem. I try to prove how can i get the eigenvalue above and proof the existence of the infimum.

Comment: Jus another observation: due to the properties of the convolution, your vanishing condition on $u(x,t)$ implies that even $J$ must have a compact support for otherwise neither $u(x,t)$ nor $u_t(x,t)$ can vanish outside $\Omega$. To be precise, the requirement is stronger: you should have that $\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}$ $$ \supp{J} + \supp{u}\Subset \Omega$$ for otherwise again the vanishing condition is not feasible (see [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4593090/convolution-of-distributions-compact-support/4593169#4593169) for the details)